# Add activity to backstack on Android

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I have an activity which I start using an intent that is coming from a place I cannot create a `PendingIntent` from since it is wrapped by the Android Leanback support library.

Once the Activity starts I would like to it's "previous" activity, which means that once the user will push "back" button, he will be sent to this activity instead of exiting the app.

I've seen how to do this using `TaskStackBuilder` but as I mentioned before, I cannot provide a `PendingIntent`.

Can anyone think of a good way of doing so?

Comment: override onBackPressed() ? definitely there are neater ways. but for the given problem statement on back pressed looks simple to implement.

Comment: I'm afraid it will cause it to feel weird since the activity will only be created when I will try leaving the previous one, plus, this will cause the 
previous activity reopen each time I try to go back to it.

Comment: As I said. Information is limited. There are chances where problem can be solved using fragments. Or launching the initial Activity instead of desired activity first with proper payload in intent and using that intent to launch the desired activity from initial activity. Or using deeplinks. Many more wats if you could clearly and properly explain your use case with step by step navigation with some possible snippets of codes.